# Publish blob content to Safari's video tag

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, mobile-safari

I'm trying to publish a video fetched using an XMLHttpRequest to a `<video>`-tag in Safari on iOS 7. The content is available as a BLOB with the appropriate content type.

So far I attempted:

- Blob urls (it does not work, the Quicktime plugin has no access to the blob url)
- Using the local filesystem (it does not work, the Quicktime plugin has no access to the filesystem url)
- Data urls (it does not work, the Quicktime plugin does not resolve data urls)

It would appear like content *must* be served to the Quicktime plugin through a HTTP based server.

This brings me to the option I am currently investigating: is it possible to listen to a (random) port from within the web browser itself? This would allow for a local web server to be set up, which could open up a way of communication with the Quicktime plugin.

The question is in two parts:

1. Is it possible to listen to a port like this?
2. Are you genious and do you see a different way to send a blob to the Quicktime plugin?

All help welcome

NOTE: Safari mobile uses a Quicktime plugin for playing the content in the html5 `<video>`-tag. I am not using Quicktime directly, but through `<video>`.

Comment: Have you considered using a `<video>` tag.

Comment: Yes, i am using the video tag. The way Safari Mobile works, is that it ships off the video tag onto a Quicktime plugin.

Comment: If this might be a relief, iOS 8 Safari finally supports the thing you need.

Comment: @AndrijaPetrovic Do you have more details about this? It is still relevant for my project if I would be able to do this.

Comment: With iOS8, finally, <video> tag is not a mockup for a QuickTime plugin. It really behaves as a fully fledged <video> tag, so it finally accepts objecturls (blobs), not just url strings :)

Comment: Do you have a link with more information?